# Recommendation on probability textbook

Tags: probability, probability-theory, book-recommendation

Most posts here asked for a probability textbook which does not assume measure-theoretic background.

However, I have a quite concrete background of measure-theory and am looking for a probability textbook which is very measure-theoretic and written for pure mathematicians, not engineers.

(I am a third-year graduate student and I have studied at least 4 different real-analysis textbooks including Folland’s, Stein’s, Royden’s, Rudin’s and etc. However, I have never studied probability theory before, and I need to study this theory now.)

Comment: I believe that one should start studying the probability theory from building intuitive understanding of the main concepts of the theory. A 'very measure-theoretic' book is not the right way to start studying probabilities.

Comment: In my opinion the best book on basic measure theoretic probability theory is the one by Kai Lai Chung.

Comment: I guess [*this posting*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239431/book-recommendations-for-probability) might also help.

Answer (score 3):

Many years ago, when I did my preparation for the measure theory exam, one of the main sources for my studies was *[Measure and Integration Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3110167190)* by Heinz Bauer. It was perfect for starters providing an easy to read, solid and instructive introduction into the subject.

> My recommendation is the book *[Probability Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3110139359)* by H. Bauer, which is strongly based upon his book about *Measure Theory*.

In fact the book about measure theory was an integral part of the *Probability Theory* when the first editions have been published. But it has been extracted as many students wanted to have this content in a book by itself. When H. Bauer followed these suggestions, he also did a rework of the *Probability Theory* but with strong focus on his *Measure Theory*.